# chisq.test doesn't print results when in a loop

Tags: r, statistics, for-loop

I don't think I need to explain exactly what the code does. The point is that while performing the chisq.test outside the loop, I get a result like this (expected):

```
        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  observed 
X-squared = 185912, df = 5, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

but when I try to do the test in a loop, the expected result does not appear

```
total <- dim(crs$dataset_init)[1]
expected.fr <- cl.popul / total

for (i in 1:dim(cl.vs.Onerall)[1] ) {
        if (cl.vs.Onerall[i,1] > 0) {
             observed <- cl.vs.Onerall[i,2:(clust_no + 1)]

             print(rownames(cl.vs.Onerall)[i])
             chisq.test(observed, p=expected.fr)
             print("------------------------------")
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you get an output at all - so do rownames and the dashes show up?

Comment: Do you notice anything missing from the middle of your three lines of output??

Comment: Yes rownames and dashes do show up

Comment: hint: print print print.

Comment: Use print. And furthermore, dim(object)[1] on your matrix is brutal: use nrow(object) instead.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, just use `print` to ensure the results of the test are printed to the console. Besides the line with the chisquare test, the rest of your code should remain the same.

```
total <- dim(crs$dataset_init)[1]
expected.fr <- cl.popul / total

for (i in 1:dim(cl.vs.Onerall)[1] ) {
        if (cl.vs.Onerall[i,1] > 0) {
             observed <- cl.vs.Onerall[i,2:(clust_no + 1)]

             print(rownames(cl.vs.Onerall)[i])
             print(chisq.test(observed, p=expected.fr)) # edited line
             print("------------------------------")
    }
}
```